# Modify .htaccess for codeigniter URLS

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2

I am trying to remove the index.php from the url in codeigniter. Rewrite mod scripts are all over the place but I can't find the .htaccess file!! I tried looking in the root directory and everywhere else, but no luck.

From what I read it should be in application folder and when I go there i find the .htaccess file and all it has is deny from all. This is not the same content every one else is sharing online before modification.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't find it; you create it along side with your index.php file with this contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

> In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php,
>   images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php
>   file.

[Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/).

Comment: Ok. I deleted the one that existed and created new one and added the code above. If i remove the index.php from url, I still get an error that it was not found.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows ( for future references)

Create the .htaccess file in the root of the codeigniter application (where you got system, application, etc folders).

Paste this code in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Open config.php and change `index = "index.php" to ""`. Things should work now.